# Как убрать классы у всех элементов, а изменить одному выбранному

Tags: javascript, html

Есть несколько элементов списка в html, хочу сделать чтобы при нажатии, добавлялся класс **red** к нажатому, а у других удалялся этот класс если он есть, и при нажатии на один и тот же элемент если есть класс **red** тоже убирался. Всё работает, при нажатии на каждый элемент, добавляется класс **red**, а у других убирается, но если нажать на этот же элемент, класс не убирается, что я делаю не так?

```
<ul>
 <li id="item1" onClick="toggleClass(1);">Item 1</li>
 <li id="item2" onClick="toggleClass(2);">Item 2</li>
 <li id="item3" onClick="toggleClass(3);">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<script>
function toggleClass(id) {
    const allLi = document.querySelectorAll('li')
    const thisLi = document.querySelector('#item'+id)
    allLi.forEach((item) => {
        item.classList.remove('red')
    })
    thisLi.classList.toggle('red')
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы удаляете у ВСЕХ класс **red**, а потом добавляете. Надо исключить удаление у текущего элемента:

```
function toggleClass(id) {
    const allLi = document.querySelectorAll('li')
    const thisLi = document.querySelector('#item'+id)
    allLi.forEach((item) => {
        if ('item'+id !== item.id) {
           item.classList.remove('red')
        }
    }
    thisLi.classList.toggle('red')
}
```

Comment: Точно! Как я мог такую логику пропустить... Спасибо!

P.S. я только начал изучать JS :)