# При нажатии на кнопку меняется ее стиль

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку менялся ее стиль, а именно - появлялось подчеркивание (и сохранялось). Сначала пыталась схитрить и через `:active` и свойство `transition: 999999s` все провернуть, но нужно, чтобы при нажатии на соседнюю кнопку стиль предыдущей возвращался в дефолт. Вопрос знатокам - как? сss/js - не важно. Можно просто ткнуть меня в нужную документацию, буду рада и этому.

Comment: [Может поможет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1489620/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b-%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83) - как раз примерно такой же вопрос был

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.x:focus{text-decoration: underline 5px red;}
```

```html
<input type='button' value='ok' class='x'>
<input type='button' value='ok' class='x'>
<input type='button' value='ok' class='x'>
```

после клика по кнопке, каретка фокуса остается на ней до любого клика мимо неё.

а вообще...

> нужно, чтобы при нажатии на соседнюю кнопку стиль предыдущей возвращался в дефолт

может `<input type='radio'>` и `<label>`?

Comment: Спасибо! Первый вариант отлично зашел. Я и забыла про фокус.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте кнопке класс `"selected"`, который будет отвечать за подчеркивание.Назначьте обработчик события `"click"` для кнопки. Внутри обработчика события используйте метод `toggle()` класса `classList` для добавления или удаления класса `"selected"` у кнопки. Добавьте слушатель события `click` на все кнопки, и внутри обработчика события используйте метод `remove()` класса `classList` у всех кнопок, кроме нажатой.
CSS:

```
.selected {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

JS:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
buttons.forEach(button => {
   button.addEventListener("click", event => {
      buttons.forEach(b => b.classList.remove("selected"));
      event.target.classList.toggle("selected");
   });
});
```

Этот код позволит вам добавлять и удалять класс `"selected"` у кнопки при клике на нее, а также удалять класс у других кнопок. При этом вам не понадобится свойство `transition` и состояние `:active`.

Либо назначьте обработчик события `"click"` для кнопки. В JavaScript добавьте слушатель события на каждую кнопку и обработчик события, который будет добавлять и удалять класс `"selected"` у кнопки при клике:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
buttons.forEach(button => {
   button.addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.classList.toggle("selected");
   });
});
```

Добавьте слушатель события `click` на все кнопки, и внутри обработчика события используйте метод `remove()` класса `classList` у всех кнопок кроме нажатой:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
buttons.forEach(button => {
   button.addEventListener("click", function(){
      buttons.forEach(b => b.classList.remove("selected"));
      this.classList.add("selected");
   });
});
```